# Python SMTP sending duplicate emails on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, email, smtp, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a simple door alarm system using the raspberry pi. I made a simple switch which is attached to the door. The program is intended to send me a text via SMTP when the door is opened (HIGH) and then send me another text when the input returns to low.

The problem is that it is sending 2 texts for each alert. The time stamps on the texts show them to be off by about half a second. The interesting thing is that this seems to be unique to the pi. I modified the code to replace the GPIO inputs with user inputed 1's and 0's and did not receive duplicate texts. Below is a subset of my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, circuit wise, I'm pulling off the 3,3v PIN 1 and am running that through a 1K ohm resistor before returning to PIN 11.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import smtplib
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sys import exit

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

doorstatus = 1

def sendalert(msg):

    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login('MyEmail', 'Password')
    server.sendmail('MyEmail', 'MyNumber@vtext.com', msg)
    server.quit()

    print msg

    return

def doorchange(msg):
    etime = str(datetime.now())
    etime = etime.split(':')
    etime = ",".join(etime)

    message = msg + etime

    sendalert(message)

    return

try:
    while True:

        time.sleep(1)

        if GPIO.input(11) == 1 and doorstatus == 1:
            text = "Alert! Door has been opened. "
            doorchange(text)
            doorstatus = 0
            time.sleep(1)

        elif GPIO.input(11) == 0 and doorstatus == 0:
            text = "Door has been closed. "
            doorchange(text)
            doorstatus = 1
            time.sleep(1)

        else:
            pass

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a bouncing issue. That means that when the door opens or close, the GPIO status changes several times between 0 and 1 before stabilizing.

This can be fixed either by hardware (using anti-bouncing circuitry which consists on adding a capacitor in parallel of your resistor) or more easily programmatically. This documentation explains how to debounce (see switch debounce section):

http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/

That will of course make you change a bit your logic:

```
GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, doorchanged, bouncetime=500)

def doorchanged():
    etime = str(datetime.now())
    etime = etime.split(':')
    etime = ",".join(etime)

    if GPIO.input(11) == 1:
        text = "Alert! Door has been opened. "
    else:
        text = "Alert! Door has been closed. "

    sendalert(text + etime)
```